# Writing spinner and switch data to text file Android

Tags: android

So I have my spinner which i will be able to select different servers and write that selected data to a text file to be retrieved by other apps. On its own this was working fine.

I needed to add another part to this which was a switch to confirm basically true or false for encryption, and with that the aim was to store a string to be called later in the file output stream.

I seem to have got confused somewhere adding the two separate strings in the fos and one way i tried gave me and error regarding 'byte' + 'byte' not being allowed. The way i have it at the moment runs however i get error in my logcats

so i need some help finding which part is broken and why it won't accept my strings and also how to fix it

the logs

```
        06-07 03:05:05.508 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.dooves.spinnertest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.dooves.spinnertest rsrc of package null
    06-07 03:05:05.528 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dooves.spinnertest-1/lib/arm
    06-07 03:05:05.558 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
    06-07 03:05:06.768 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dooves.spinnertest-1/lib/arm
    06-07 03:05:06.918 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.dooves.spinnertest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.dooves.spinnertest rsrc of package null
    06-07 03:05:06.918 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.dooves.spinnertest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.dooves.spinnertest rsrc of package null
    06-07 03:05:07.068 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    06-07 03:05:07.208 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest I/Switch: Immediately mode attached=false laidOut=false
    06-07 03:05:07.208 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest I/Switch: Immediately mode attached=false laidOut=false
    06-07 03:05:07.248 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
    06-07 03:05:07.248 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{95a1ffb I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    06-07 03:05:07.248 18344-18547/com.dooves.spinnertest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    06-07 03:05:07.318 18344-18547/com.dooves.spinnertest I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ia10634f51b)
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
                                                                        Build Date: 01/28/16 Thu
                                                                        Local Branch: ss
                                                                        Remote Branch: 
                                                                        Local Patches: 
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch: 
    06-07 03:05:07.328 18344-18547/com.dooves.spinnertest D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x9f28b7c4
    06-07 03:05:07.328 18344-18547/com.dooves.spinnertest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    06-07 03:05:07.438 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
    06-07 03:05:07.568 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-07 03:05:07.598 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ec4ad8a time:38728975
    06-07 03:05:14.398 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    06-07 03:05:14.528 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
    06-07 03:05:14.568 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
    06-07 03:05:14.578 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@ebd8dc7
    06-07 03:05:14.578 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6d22ff4
    06-07 03:05:14.578 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6d22ff4
    06-07 03:05:14.588 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{1528992 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
    06-07 03:05:14.668 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
    06-07 03:05:14.678 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-07 03:05:15.398 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    06-07 03:05:15.518 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
    06-07 03:05:15.938 18344-18547/com.dooves.spinnertest D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xadcbd280 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0x9df14170
    06-07 03:05:15.938 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
    06-07 03:05:16.378 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    06-07 03:05:16.478 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
    06-07 03:05:18.278 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    06-07 03:05:18.388 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
    06-07 03:05:18.398 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: &true
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.nio.charset.Charset.forNameUEE(Charset.java:322)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:534)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at com.dooves.spinnertest.MainActivity.saveSettings(MainActivity.java:114)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err: Caused by: java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: &true
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkCharsetName(Charset.java:197)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:295)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     at java.nio.charset.Charset.forNameUEE(Charset.java:320)
    06-07 03:05:18.408 18344-18344/com.dooves.spinnertest W/System.err:     ... 14 more
```

From this i am unsure what to change to correct this. If i remove the '&' from the string i get the same logcat but saying 'true' rather than '&true'

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    String SelectedServer;
    Switch passSwitch;
    String PasswordEncryption;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.serverUrl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        passSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.passencrypt);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SelectedServer = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });

        passSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    PasswordEncryption = "&true";
                } else {
                    PasswordEncryption = "&false";
                }
            }
        });
    }


            public void saveSettings(View view) {

                File txtFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder/");
                if (!txtFolder.exists()) {
                    txtFolder.mkdir();
                }
                File file = new File(txtFolder, "setting.txt");
                String.valueOf(SelectedServer.getBytes());
                String.valueOf(PasswordEncryption.getBytes());
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(SelectedServer.getBytes(PasswordEncryption));
                    fos.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Settings Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

    }
```

The spinner is populated from string array in the strings.xml file and currently will contain only 'server1, server2, server3, server4'.
the end result should show a saved setting.txt file with eg, server1&false or server3&true.

any help appreciated

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the issue:

```
fos.write(SelectedServer.getBytes(PasswordEncryption));
```

`String.getBytes(String charset)` requires a valid `charset` parameter such as "UTF8". Instead, you are passing `PasswordEncryption` which equals "$true" or "$false". Neither of those is a valid charset.

If you do this `fos.write(SelectedServer + PasswordEncryption);` then the output should be like `server1&false`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately this didn't work and i was getting cannot resolve method 'write(java.lang.string)' error. However it did prompt me for a different approach so was still helpful.

I created a new string called serverSettings and then added that values like you did above - serverSettings = SelectedServer + PasswordEcryption;

then i was able to call it as a was trying previously 
fos.write(serverSettings.getBytes());

so thanks for the input and steering me in the wright direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else was trying this (i doubt many will be as much as a beginner as i am) but this resolved the issue.

i created another string to store the combine values of strings SelectedServer and PasswordEncryption and added those values together and called the new string value in my code rather than trying to add the 2 later.
Not sure if it is the right approach but it worked for what i wanted.

```
String serverSettings;
    serverSettings = selectServer + passwordEncryption;
```

and for using in my fos

```
File file = new File(txtFolder, "setting.txt");
    String.valueOf(serverSettings.getBytes());
        try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(serverSettings.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```